# Can't compile libpq-fe.h no such file or dir on cpp

Tags: c++, gcc, libpq

I tried to compile source that using libpq-fe.h as header. This is my header

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

#include "libpq-fe.h"

using namespace std;
```

I compiled this with make command, and it gives me error #include "libpq-fe.h" no such file or directory. I am using ubuntu and gcc 4.8.4 as compiler.

Here is my makefiles

```
CC = /usr/bin/g++
LD = /usr/bin/g++
PG_HOMEDIR = /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/
CPPFLAGS = -O3
CPPFLAGS += -I${PG_HOMEDIR}/include

...

LOAD_OBJS = bulkload.o loadgraph/load.o util/util.o util/graphutil.o db/pgsql_db.o config.o orthology/ortholog.o io/graphio.o io/gdf.o
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The path `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/` is not a standard Ubuntu path (it looks more like a OSX path), is it custom on your system?

Comment: I changed it to ubuntu standard path PG_HOMEDIR = /usr/local/bin. But it still gives me the same error. I know it should be home of postgres installation, but I installed postgres just using terminal and have no information about where is the location of postgres installation.

Comment: When the `/bin/` directories are where *programs* are stored, `/lib/` is where *libraries* (shared or static) and `/include/` is where the *header* files are stored. I also implore you to learn the [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command, which can be used to find files.